# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - ERROR

Tags: oracle

I'm running this query and it returns this error. What could be wrong?
I have no idea what could be causing the error.
I'm using this query in a datawindow object in powerbuilder 19.

`SELECT * from ( SELECT '                                                            ' as data_hora_documento, '     ' as ind_horario_verao, '     ' as ind_evento_retroativo, '       ' as atendimento, '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ' as justificava_retroativa, '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ' as pac_nome_social, psv.psv_nome, pac.PDC_COR, pac.PDC_NATURALIDADE, cde.cde_ufe_sigla, pdc_r.PDC_R_ROT, pro.pro_nome, pac.PAC_OBS, pac.pac_est_civil, pac.pac_nome_mae, pac.pac_reg, pac.pac_nome, pac.pac_pront, pac.pac_sexo, pac.pac_nasc, pac.pac_fone, cnv.cnv_nome, pac.pac_mcnv, pac.pac_cnv, pac.pac_end, pac.pac_comp, pac.pac_cep, pac.pac_cid, pac.pac_uf, pac.pac_numrg, pac.pac_numcpf, pac.pac_numrg_org, pac.pac_numrg_uf, '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ' as mensagem_aprovacao FROM tbh pac left join pro on pac.PAC_PRO_COD = pro.PRO_COD left join psv on psv.psv_Cod = pac.pac_medico left join pdc_r on pac.PDC_RELIGIAO = pdc_r.PDC_R_COD LEFT JOIN cde ON pac.pdc_naturalidade_cde_cod = cde.cde_cod, cnv WHERE (pac.pac_reg = 3475184) AND ( (pac_versao = 0) OR ( ( (0 = 0) OR (0 IS NULL) ) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pdc WHERE pdc_pac_reg = 3475184 ) ) AND pac_versao = ( SELECT max(pac_versao) FROM tbh t WHERE t.pac_reg = 3475184 ) ) AND (cnv.cnv_cod = 'BRA') UNION SELECT '                                                            ' as data_hora_documento, '     ' as ind_horario_verao, '     ' as ind_evento_retroativo, '       ' as atendimento, '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ' as justificava_retroativa, '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ' as pac_nome_social, psv.psv_nome, pdc.PDC_COR, pdc.PDC_NATURALIDADE, cde.cde_ufe_sigla, pdc_r.PDC_R_ROT, pro.pro_nome, PAC_OBS, pac_est_civil, pac.pac_nome_mae, pac.pac_reg, pac.pac_nome, pac.pac_pront, pac.pac_sexo, pac.pac_nasc, pac.pac_fone, cnv.cnv_nome, pac.pac_mcnv, pac.pac_cnv, pac.pac_end, pac.pac_comp, pac.pac_cep, pac.pac_cid, pac.pac_uf, pac.pac_numrg, pac.pac_numcpf, pac.pac_numrg_org, pac.pac_numrg_uf, '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ' as mensagem_aprovacao FROM pac left join pro on pac.PAC_PRO_COD = pro.PRO_COD left join psv on psv.psv_Cod = pac.pac_medico, cnv, pdc left join pdc_r on pdc.PDC_RELIGIAO = pdc_r.PDC_R_COD LEFT JOIN cde ON pdc.pdc_naturalidade_cde_cod = cde.cde_cod WHERE (pac.pac_reg = 3475184) And ( 0 = 0 or 0 is null ) and (cnv.cnv_cod = 'BRA') and (pdc.pdc_pac_reg = pac.pac_reg) ) as pac`

Comment: Please describe what steps you have already done to locate the error. Should we debug this wall of code for you?

Comment: `cde.cde_cod, cnv` is incorrect, because the first one is a part of join condition that cannot have comma after it

Comment: It is a really bad idea to mix old-style implicit joins with modern ANSI joins (or to use implicit joins at all...) - but the actual error is probably from the final `) as pac` because you can't use `as` for table or inline view aliases. Remove that `as`, the  fix the joins, then if you still have problems simplify until the error goes away; or start from a simple working query and build it up.